# getting NaN as result of hypergeometric R function

Tags: r, function

I have a comb function like the following :

```
comb <- function(n,r) {
  factorial(n)/factorial(r)*factorial(n-r)
}
```

And also a hyper.formula that invokes `comb`:

```
hyper.formula <- function(q,m,n,k) {
  comb(m,q)*comb(n,k-q)/comb(m+n,k)
}
```

When I call `hyper.formula(7,1100,900,10)` I get `NaN` as result. I suspect there is something wrong with the number of arguments `comb(n,k-q)` the `k-q` part but cannot find the solution for it.

Comment: `factorial(1100)` is a real large number: `> factorial(1100) #> [1] Inf`.

Comment: Your `comb`-function, should it be the same as `choose(n, k)`? In this case, you are missing a pair of `( )`.

Comment: I see it should be `comb <- function(n,r) {
  factorial(n)/(factorial(r)*factorial(n-r))
}`

Comment: but how `dhyper` works then since it is `p(x) = choose(m, x) choose(n, k-x) / choose(m+n, k)`

Comment: The implementation of `choose` avoids large numbers, it's more efficient than   `factorial(n) / ( factorial(k) * factorial(n-k))`.

Comment: hum I see it , `n(n-1)...(n-k+1) / k!` for `k>1`. thanks

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** you should do as much computation as possible on the log scale. R provides a lot of convenient formulas for this. (Also, use other people's code whenever you can - I haven't looked, but I'm sure there are packages that have implementations of the hypergeometric distribution, search for "R distribution task view" ...)

Here are your functions, with the typo in `comb()` corrected (parentheses grouping the denominator):

```r
comb <- function(n,r) {
  factorial(n)/(factorial(r)*factorial(n-r))
}
hyper.formula <- function(q,m,n,k) {
  comb(m,q)*comb(n,k-q)/comb(m+n,k)
}
```

Here is a version (`hfl` = "hypergeometric function, log-scale") that uses R's built-in `lchoose()` function which returns the *log* of the binomial coefficient, doing the computations in an efficient way, then exponentiates the result at the end:

```r
hfl <- function(q, m, n, k) {
  exp(lchoose(m,q) + lchoose(n, k-q) - lchoose(m+n, k))
}
```

Comparing the original with the improved function over a scale where the original works part of the time:

```r
curve(hyper.formula(7,x,20,10), from = 20, to = 1000, log = "xy",  
    ylim = c(1e-4, 0.4))
curve(hfl(7,x,20,10), col=2, lty = 2, add=TRUE)
## dhyper() only works for integer-valued inputs ...
dd <- dhyper(7,20:1000,20,10)
points(20:1000, dd, col=4, pch=".")
```

[image: hypergeometric curves]

It's a bit hard to see, but the original function only works out to about `x=100`; the other two curves are identical with it up to that point but continue on for the entire range.

If you want to see how `dhyper()` is actually doing it, look [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c499218846d14500255efd622b5021c10ec/src/nmath/dhyper.c#L64-L74); there is some logarithmic trickery going on, but also some transformation of the original inputs. The logic is described in comments [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c499218846d14500255efd622b5021c10ec/src/nmath/dhyper.c#L24-L40).

Comment: I know there are implementations on the hyper geometric distribution. This is more of a fun test to me to check if by writing `hyper.formula` is equivalent to `dhyper`

Comment: but apparently not even writing `hyper.formula` like this with `choose` gets me the same result as `dhyper`  `hyper.formula <- function(q,m,n,k) {
  (choose(m,q)*choose(n,k-q))/choose(m+n,k)
}`

Comment: I don't think you appreciate how big those `choose()` terms can get and how quickly they can lead to numeric problems ...

Comment: hum ok so `dhyper` is probably using `hfl`.

Comment: hum I see how big it gets `choose` by `choose(1000,60)` woww